# HTML file seems to be ignoring javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

So I was following a guide to make a simple clicker game from [here](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470901/So-You-Want-An-External-JavaScript-Huh.htm/) and I tried testing it and for some reason the number wasn't incrementing, so I checked the console and it said that "`clik()` Is not defined" and when I checked the files that are loaded, it only showed the `HTML` file.
Why isn't it executing the JS file?

> Here's the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="clik(1)">Clik to add cliks</button>
<br />
Cliks: <span id="clik">0</span>
<br />
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> And here's the JS file:

```
var clik = 0;
function clik(num){
    clik = clik + num
   document.getElementById("clik").innerHTML = clik;
};
```

Keep in mind that none of this is online and I am running it locally.
Console is outputting

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

and once I click the button

```
TypeError: clik is not a function[Learn More]
```

Comment: `src` stands for "source". `scr`, not so much. :) Voting to close as Typo.

Comment: Check errors in console. May be you are giving incorrect path for javascript file.

Comment: What is this code for? `clik = clik + num` clik is function. but you add number on it.

Comment: ive changed src to scr and its still not working

Comment: Its supposed to add whatever num is to clik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var clik = 0;
function clik(num){
    clik = clik + num
   document.getElementById("clik").innerHTML = clik;
};
```

<s>when this code is parsed, there's one "variable" called clik, and i's a function</s>

first time this code is run

```
clik = clik + num;
```

now `clik` isn't a function

> actually, it's more complicated than that - function definitions are hoisted to the top of the scope, so what is actually happening is that the `var clik=0` is replacing the function before it is even run the first time. Your code is equivalent to writing

```
function clik(num){
    clik = clik + num
   document.getElementById("clik").innerHTML = clik;
};
var clik = 0;
```

and now, you can see why `clik` isn't a function even for the first user click

Your code should use a different name for the `var` - like, say `nclik`

```
var nclik = 0;
function clik(num){
    nclik = nclik + num;
   document.getElementById("clik").innerHTML = nclik;
}
```

as a side note, please note where I have and have not used a `;` there's no need for one after the `function {};` and you *should* put one after each statement (of course, that's a style issue, just putting it out there)

Comment: Yes, it is wrong code.

Comment: no any issue in script.js file

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure that all your attributes are correct, in your case: scr is not a valid attribute for script tag:

```
<script src="link/to/file.js">
```

The `type=""` attribute is not needed, the default is "text/javascript"

You can figure this out on your own if you use the built in dev tools of your browser. There you can check (under the network tab) which files are getting loaded. Here you would see that your js is never requested, which tells you, that the src parameter is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the names you gave to the variable and the function. They're not allowed to be the same. To show that it has nothing to do with the location of the script, simply put it inline like in this [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/voveficuga/2/edit?html,console,output). You get the same error.

If you change the variable name however:

```
var i = 0;
function clik(num){
    i = i + num
   document.getElementById("clik").innerHTML = i;
};
```

it [works](https://jsbin.com/bogenerupu/edit?html,console,output).

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="clik()">Clik to add cliks</button>
<br />
Cliks: <span id="clik">0</span>
<br />
<script type=javascript src="js\script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
 var count = 0 ;
        function clik(){

           count +=1;
           document.getElementById("clik").innerHTML = count;
        }
```

No need to pass the parameters in the click function..`Remove the parameter "1" in click()` .Instead we added the variable count = 0 ;

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

- replace your `\` with `/`
- make your path absolute

`<script src="/js/script.js"></script>`

As a general Tip:

That error should show up in the console ;)

Comment: Ive done so and still, nothing happens.

Comment: already found the answer on top, glad we could help. Have fun coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Please change this syntax

```
<script type=javascript src="js/script.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text\javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

after this changed your code working fine